# How to select the maximum value in each group where group having a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

How to select the maximum value record of grouped data on multiple columns where (group has number of positive entries > number of negative entries).

```
Name,Marks,ID,Location
steve,  5   1   irving
steve,  2   2   irving
steve,  6   3   toledo
steve,  3   4   irving
steve,  1   5   irving
john,   6   1   london
john,   4   2   london
john,   1   3   hills
abhi,  -2   1   akron
abhi,  -3   2   akron
abhi,   2   3   akron
abhi,  -5   4   akron
abhi,   1   5   market
```

Here I want to select  the maximum id of same person and location where number of positive marks > number of negative marks.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please dont post links to pictures of code.  Edit the question and put in as text.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you out. I created the temp table for testing. I added a couple of rows of data to test the extra filtering you requested. I wasn't sure if you wanted to see the number of records, so I commented them out, so it is there if you want it.

```
CREATE TABLE #aa(
[Name] VARCHAR(10),
Marks int,
ID int,
[Location] VARCHAR(20));

INSERT #aa ([Name],Marks,ID,[Location])
VALUES ('steve',5,1,'irving'),
   ('steve',2,2,'irving'),
   ('steve',6,3,'toledo'),
   ('steve',3,4,'irving'),
   ('steve',1,5,'irving'),
   ('steve',1,6,'irving'),
   ('john',6,1,'london'),
   ('john',4,2,'london'),
   ('john',1,3,'hills'),
   ('john',5,4,'london'),
   ('john',2,5,'hills'),
   ('abhi',-2,1,'akron'),
   ('abhi',-3,2,'akron'),
   ('abhi',2,3,'akron'),
   ('abhi',-5,4,'akron'),
   ('abhi',1,5,'market');

--Common Table Expression (CTE) to get groups with more positive marks
WITH groupValue AS
( SELECT [Name],[Location]--,Count(*) AS 'Records'
  FROM #aa
  GROUP BY [Name],[LOCATION]
  HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Marks > 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) > 0
     AND Count(*) <> 1 -- Making sure the total records is greater than 1
     AND Count(*) % 2 <> 0 --Finding odd numbers by dividing by 2 and
                           -- checking the remainder. Even numbers will 
                           -- always have a remainder of 0. 
                           )

SELECT a.[Name],a.[Location],MAX(ID) 'MaxId'--,groupValue.Records
FROM groupValue
 JOIN #aa a ON groupValue.Name = a.Name
           AND groupValue.Location = a.Location
GROUP BY a.[NAME],a.[Location]--,groupValue.Records
ORDER BY a.[NAME],a.[Location]

DROP TABLE #aa
```

Comment: Thanks Jason it is working. I want one more condition such that the max ID is selected only for the groups having more than one one record and odd number of records along for the above query.

Comment: I'm playing with it now.